# Point-in-time recovery Google Cloud SQL can't find a successful backup

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We're running a Google Cloud SQL instance and I accidentally re-migrated a database over the top of the live database 14 days after it was initially migrated using the same mysqldump file - essentially rolling it back 14 days!

So I'm piecing data in the tables back together as new entries are using increment IDs previously used [thats not a problem] but I need to spin up a clone of the database from the moment just before I dropped and loaded the database.

I've got the point-in-time I need to use using:

```
mysqlbinlog --read-from-remote-server -v -uusername -ppassword mysql-bin.000001 -h 000.000.000.000 -P 3306 --start-datetime="2016-09-20 14:45:55" --stop-datetime="2016-09-20 14:47:00"
```

But when I put in the **Binary log file name** mysql-bin.000001
and the **Recovery position** 70869547 (found from scanning through the mysqlbinlog result) it responses with:

*"A successful backup for carrying out the operation was not found."*

It prompts to wait for the next daily backup, but the last backup was just 3 hours ago and I tried the same yesterday...

Any thoughts on why this would happen?

Comment: The `--start-datetime` and `--stop-datetime` is a lot more helpful than trying to browser through the binlogs in the database using positions. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think its simply that I'm trying to recover the data back to the 20th and the oldest backup is the 21st! Google only keeps 7 days worth of backups.
But I hope that the method above helps someone find their backup point quicker in future.